# Make an action when searchBar cancel button is fire

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uisearchbar

I have a tableView with a searchBar.
I want to reload my tableView data when the searchBar cancel Button is tapped.

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    println("cancel button tapped")

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

i set :

```
   UISearchBarDelegate
```

and :

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.searchBar.delegate = self

}
```

What is weird is that  searchBarSearchButtonClicked is working good.

What did i miss ?

Comment: Are you using the search bar and search display controller? Why do you manually need to write the implementation of the cancel button? It is automatically handled by the Search bar

Comment: The cancel button is working but I can't reload my tableView. Not using it with a display controller

Comment: Have you specified a @IBOutlet ?

Comment: No it s just the regular cancel button embed in the search controller